# MInutes and seconds with 2 digits

Tags: swift

I have an input in seconds I store it in a var:

```
var totalTime = 60
```

I want to show it with 2 digits for minutes and 2 digits for seconds:
01:00

What I have tried:

```
let minutes = String(totalTime / 60)  
let seconds = String(totalTime % 60)
label.text = minutes + ":" + seconds
```

This gives me: 1:0
But I want 01:00

I tried and It does not work:

```
label.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your second approach is that it expects an integer and you are passing a string.

```
let minutes = totalTime / 60 
let seconds = totalTime % 60

label.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
```